# jquery code execution is happening in other code block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made this custom ajax function to avoid writing ajax code multiple times. My issue is that if there is no option passed for `failcmds` variable & `obj.status` is `"failure"`, then also code execution  moves to the `succcmds` code block & execute available commands. `e.g. reload(2500)` in the example code.

Pls help me to identify the missing part.

**Custom Ajax function**

```
function gr(url, varr, succcmds, failcmds, divid, drestype) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: varr, 
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loadingDiv').show();
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#loadingDiv').hide();
        },
        success: function(response){
            if(response){
                var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                if(obj.status == "failure") { 
                    console.log('failcmds : ' + failcmds);
                    if(obj.message) { 
                        gm("e",obj.message); 
                    }
                    if(typeof failcmds === "undefined") {
                        return;
                    }else {
                        $.each(failcmds,function(index, value) {
                            value;
                        });
                    }
                }else if(obj.status == "success"){
                    if(obj.message) { 
                        gm("s",obj.message); 
                    }
                    if(succcmds && succcmds !== null) {             
                        $.each(succcmds,function(ind, val) {
                            val; 
                        });
                    }
                    if (divid && divid !== null){ 
                        if(drestype && drestype == "html"){
                            $("#"+ divid).html(obj.data);
                        }else{
                            $("#"+ divid).append(obj.data); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                gm("e", "Invalid Request");
            }
        },
        error: function(){}
    });
}
```

**Sample usage of function**

```
$(document).on("click", '.xyz', function() {
    var d = $(this).prop('id');
    var data = 'd='+ $(this).prop('id') + '&typ=sts';
    gm('c','Are you sure you want to do this?');
    $(document).on("click", '#btnYes', function() {
        var sarr = [reload(2500)];
        gr(basepath + "deletereq?", data, sarr);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> then also code execution moves to the succcmds code block & execute available commands

No it doesn't.  You executed those commands before you even called your function:

```
var sarr = [reload(2500)];
```

This will *execute* `reload(2500)` and put the *result* of that execution in the `sarr` array.

Instead, wrap that in a function:

```
var sarr = [function () { reload(2500); }];
```

Then you can later execute that function where you like:

```
$.each(succcmds,function(ind, val) {
    val(); 
});
```

Basically you want your "commands" to be executable functions, not the results of executed functions.

Comment: Thanks @David. It worked perfectly. But i am still unclear on one thing. How come {sarr} is getting executed in {obj.status == "failure"} block where it is not available or being called. I am 100% certain that {obj.status} is failure. Hence it should only execute {failcmds} variable commands (if available), which are being called in this particular section.

Comment: @techworld: Because in your original code the commands were always executed right away, not being held for later execution.  So no matter what the result is, any commands you store have already been invoked.  Instead, store functions which would later invoke the commands and conditionally invoke those based on the result.